# Equivalent of Math.Min & Math.Max for Dates?

Tags: .net

What's the quickest and easiest way to get the Min (or Max) value between two dates? Is there an equivalent to Math.Min (& Math.Max) for dates?

I want to do something like:

```
 if (Math.Min(Date1, Date2) < MINIMUM_ALLOWED_DATE) {
      //not allowed to do this
 }
```

Obviously the above Math.Min doesn't work because they're dates.

Answer (score 502, accepted):

There is no overload for DateTime values, but you can get the long value `Ticks` that is what the values contain, compare them and then create a new DateTime value from the result:

```
new DateTime(Math.Min(Date1.Ticks, Date2.Ticks))
```

(Note that the DateTime structure also contains a `Kind` property, that is not retained in the new value. This is normally not a problem; if you compare DateTime values of different kinds the comparison doesn't make sense anyway.)

Comment: this seemed to me to be closest to a one line replacement/equivalent for Math.Min but the other answers were great too, for completeness

Comment: -, you completely loose every information (except the ticks) of the original `System.DateTime`-instance

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: The only information that exist in a `DateTime` value is the `Ticks` and the `Kind` properties. All other properties are derived from those.

Comment: @Guffa `Kind` is the main issue when talking about and/or using globalization - sorry for considering `Kind` as the main benefit and therefore using *every information* :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: If you are comparing dates of different kinds, you can't just compare them straight off anyway. I already covered this in the answer.

Comment: @Guffa thanks for clarification and sry - but still ... creating a new  `System.DateTime`-instance for each comparison-result seems *wrong* for me ... (even that i am unsure of the *magic* performance impact ...)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: The difference from copying the value is minimal. The constructor makes a range check on the `Ticks` value, other than that it's just an assignment.

Comment: @Guffa "can't just compare them straight off anyway" however this code thinks that it can...

Comment: @Iain: You always *can* compare them, but if you compare values that are not comparable, the outcome is useless. It's just the same as with any other values that are not comparable, like comparing a distance in kilometers with a distance in miles; you can compare the values just fine, but it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: -1 for handwaving about Kind.  As shown in @user450 's answer, it's quite easy to convert both times to UTC and compare them safely without discarding information.

Comment: Interresting idea. Unfortunately, 1: DateTime.Kind is lost, 2: it involves many additional computation than a (x > y ? x : y) - As it is valid, this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 641):

There's no built in method to do that. You can use the expression:

```
(date1 > date2 ? date1 : date2)
```

to find the maximum of the two.

You can write a generic method to calculate `Min` or `Max` for any type (provided that `Comparer<T>.Default` is set appropriately):

```
public static T Max<T>(T first, T second) {
    if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(first, second) > 0)
        return first;
    return second;
}
```

You can use LINQ too:

```
new[]{date1, date2, date3}.Max()
```

Comment: The `LINQ` way is the best way!

Comment: @SerjSagan `LINQ` is the **worst** way. It has the slowest speed and allocates additional memory. See my post regarding benchmarking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75869992/9232174

Comment: It's not always about performance, in fact, if performance is not an issue then clean readable code is FAR more important.

Comment: All of these options are extremely simple, clean and readable. There is no reason whatsoever to initialise an array to perform this comparison.

Answer (score 60):

`Linq.Min()` / `Linq.Max()` approach:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2001,1,1);

DateTime minresult = new[] { date1,date2 }.Min();
DateTime maxresult = new[] { date1,date2 }.Max();
```

Answer (score 41):

How about:

```
public static T Min<T>(params T[] values)
{
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    switch(values.Length) {
        case 0: throw new ArgumentException();
        case 1: return values[0];
        case 2: return comparer.Compare(values[0],values[1]) < 0
               ? values[0] : values[1];
        default:
            T best = values[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(values[i], best) < 0)
                {
                    best = values[i];
                }
            }
            return best;
    }        
}
// overload for the common "2" case...
public static T Min<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y) < 0 ? x : y;
}
```

Works with any type that supports `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`.

Actually, with LINQ, another alternative is:

```
var min = new[] {x,y,z}.Min();
```

Comment: For the first method, it can just be `return values.Min();` after the null check.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to use use `Linq.Max()` but call it more like `Math.Max`, you can do something like this very short expression body:

```
public static DateTime Max(params DateTime[] dates) => dates.Max();
[...]
var lastUpdatedTime = DateMath.Max(feedItemDateTime, assemblyUpdatedDateTime);
```

Answer (score 20):

```
public static class DateTool
{
    public static DateTime Min(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return (x.ToUniversalTime() < y.ToUniversalTime()) ? x : y;
    }
    public static DateTime Max(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return (x.ToUniversalTime() > y.ToUniversalTime()) ? x : y;
    }
}
```

This allows the dates to have different 'kinds' and returns the instance that was passed in (not returning a new DateTime constructed from Ticks or Milliseconds).

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void MinTest2()
    {
        DateTime x = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime y = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Local);

        //Presumes Local TimeZone adjustment to UTC > 0
        DateTime actual = DateTool.Min(x, y);
        Assert.AreEqual(x, actual);
    }
```

Note that this test would fail East of Greenwich...

Comment: Why not just drop the ToUniversalTime() part?

Comment: Using ToUniversalTime allows the comparison of mixed DateTime Kinds.

Answer (score 19):

For anybody wondering about the performance of some of the answers previously provided, I ran benchmarks on a few of them. I used ternary operators, LINQ, and Math.max to determine the best solution for speed and memory.

##### Ternary

```
return a > b ? a : b;
```

- Average Speed: 0.0198 nanoseconds
- Additional Memory Allocation: none
- Garbage Collection Time: none

##### Math.max

```
return new DateTime(Math.Max(a.Ticks, b.Ticks));
```

- Average Speed: 2.4346 nanoseconds
- Additional Memory Allocation: none
- Garbage Collection Time: none

##### LINQ

```
return new[]{a, b}.Max();
```

- Average Speed: 22.8383 nanoseconds
- Additional Memory Allocation: 72 bytes
- Garbage Collection Time: 0.0057 nanoseconds

###### Environment

.Net Version: 6.0

C# Version: 10.0

Configuration: Release

###### References

Benchmarking was done using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) 0.13.5

[image: DateTime comparison benchmarks]

---

### TLDR

A ternary operator is the most performant method by far. It performs over 100x faster than the runner-up and allocates no additional memory.

Comment: what about about a basic if statement?  Why use ternary?

Comment: The c# compiler converts ternary arguments into simple if statements. It's effectively the same thing. `return a > b ? a : b;` becomes `if (a > b) { return a; } else { return b; }`

Answer (score 7):

How about a `DateTime` extension method?

```
public static DateTime MaxOf(this DateTime instance, DateTime dateTime)
{
    return instance > dateTime ? instance : dateTime;
}
```

Usage:

```
var maxDate = date1.MaxOf(date2);
```

Comment: I would prefer to use it as `DateTime.MaxOf(dt1, dt2)`, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @ZachSmith You cannot overload the DateTime class because it is not partial. Maybe we can use DateTimeHelper.Max(dt1, dt2)

Comment: @shtse8 - what do you mean by overloading? i was thinking of adding an extension method. but have since learnt that cannot be done without an instantiated instance. sounds like you are saying that adding an extension method is a form of overloading? i've never considered that.. is that correct? now that I think about it... what exactly does overloading mean?

Comment: @ZachSmith Oh, I thought you are adding an extension called "DateTime.MaxOf(dt1, dt2)" just like "DateTime.Now" which is based on DateTime static members.

Answer (score 2):

Put these two methods in a Utility class and use them to get Min/Max of any number of DateTimes:

```
public static DateTime Min(params DateTime[] dates)
{
    if (dates.Length == 1) return dates[0];

    long minTicks = dates[0].Ticks;

    for (int i = 1; i < dates.Length; i++)
    {
        minTicks = Math.Min(minTicks, dates[i].Ticks);
    }

    return new DateTime(minTicks);
}

public static DateTime Max(params DateTime[] dates)
{
    if (dates.Length == 1) return dates[0];

    long maxTicks = dates[0].Ticks;

    for (int i = 1; i < dates.Length; i++)
    {
        maxTicks = Math.Max(maxTicks, dates[i].Ticks);
    }

    return new DateTime(maxTicks);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can convert dates into Number primitive with Date.parse(), then we can use Math.min() and Math.max() for processing and storing. With that primitive we can render in any format we want.
It's a 2-3 steps process, but we virtually eliminates the risk of getting funky results.

```js
const unixTimeZero = Date.parse('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
const javaScriptRelease = Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT');
const today = Date.parse(new Date());
const d1 = Date.parse(new Date("2004-02-01"));
const d2 = Date.parse(new Date("2017-01"));
const d3 = Date.parse(new Date("2018"))
const t = [unixTimeZero, d1, d2, d3, today, javaScriptRelease];
const min = Math.min(...t)
const max = Math.max(...t)
console.log(unixTimeZero); // expected output: 0
console.log(javaScriptRelease); // expected output: 818035920000
console.log(today);
console.log(t);
console.log(["unixMin: " + min, "earliestDate: " + new Date(min).toUTCString()]);
console.log(["unixMax: " + max, "latestDate: " + new Date(max).toDateString()]);
```

Comment: the question is about C#

Comment: My bad.. Didn't see that. i'm stoopid

Answer (score -7):

```
// Two different dates
var date1 = new Date(2013, 05, 13); 
var date2 = new Date(2013, 04, 10) ;
// convert both dates in milliseconds and use Math.min function
var minDate = Math.min(date1.valueOf(), date2.valueOf());
// convert minDate to Date
var date = new Date(minDate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5CR37/

Comment: Good suggestion (really), but without description it's hard to find why it is good. Please describe where the trick is. Without the description it's just a block of code and not an answer.

Comment: question is tagged .NET not Javascript

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice .NET. Anyway, we can find min date on client side and send it to server.

Comment: You assume that we are talking about asp, which is not necessarily right. It also would be quite stupid to calcluate the difference on the Client, because there are far more risks (JavaScript disabled) , it would generate unnecessary traffic and it would be (depending on the network speed) slower

Comment: Create a datecomparison microservice running in node.js and then you can call it to answer the original question