# Find overlapping dates in 2 lists and return overlapping period

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 lists that contain UTC dates. To determine if the lists contain overlapping dates I am doing the following:

```
list1.Where(
    x =>
    list2.Any(
    y =>
    x.StartDate < y.EndDate &&
    y.StartDate < x.EndDate));
```

Is there a way to actually return the overlapping periods? These lists are unique within themselves in that list1 will not contain overlapping dates, and list2 will not contain overlapping dates within iteself.

For example, if I have the 2 lists containing the following start and end date times

```
list 1:
   1/1 5AM - 1/1 10PM
   1/2 4AM - 1/2 8AM
list 2:
   1/1 10AM - 1/1 11AM
   1/1 4PM - 1/1 5PM
   1/2 5AM - 10PM
```

I would want to return:

```
1/1 10AM - 1/1 11AM
1/1 4PM - 1/1 5Pm
1/2 5AM - 1/2 8AM
```

The dates will never be NULL.

I'm thinking taking the MAX of the 2 starts and the MIN of the 2 ends would work, but not sure how that would look syntactically

Comment: So   the last item in the result 1/2 5AM - 1/2 8AM and not 1/2 5AM -  1/2 10 PM?

Comment: Correct its until 8AM only because they dont overlap anymore after 8AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following `DateRange` class:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and the followingNaïve [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) comparison functions:

```
public static DateTime MinDate(DateTime first, DateTime second)
{
    return first < second ? first : second;
}

public static DateTime MaxDate(DateTime first, DateTime second)
{
    return first > second ? first : second;
}
```

you can use the following `Linq`:

```
list1.SelectMany(x =>
    list2.Where(y => x.StartDate < y.EndDate && y.StartDate < x.EndDate)
         .Select(y => new { first = x, second = y })))
             // Here you will have:
             // {
             //     x = (1/1 5AM - 1/1 10PM), y = (1/1 10AM - 1/1 11AM),
             //     x = (1/1 5AM - 1/1 10PM), y = (1/1 4PM - 1/1 5PM),
             //     x = (1/2 4AM - 1/2 8AM), y = (1/2 5AM - 10PM)
             // }
    .Select(x => new DateRange(MaxDate(x.first.StartDate, x.second.StartDate), MinDate(x.first.EndDate, x.second.EndDate))
             // Here you will have:
             // {
             //     (1/1 10AM - 1/1 11AM),
             //     (1/1 4PM - 1/1 5PM),
             //     (1/2 5AM - 1/2 8AM)
             // }
```

Notice that this kind of `Linq` query will be an ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** when if the `Lists` are sorted this can be achieved in ***O(n)*** with an algorithm similar to [sorted array merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array).

Comment: Must say a very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the right answer with your example.

```
    class DateSpan
    {
        public DateTime StartDate;
        public DateTime EndDate;

        public DateSpan(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            StartDate = start;
            EndDate = end;
        }

        public DateSpan(DateTime start, int duration)
        {
            StartDate = start;
            EndDate = start.AddHours(duration);
        }
    }

    public void TestStuff()
    {
        var dates1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
        dates1.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0), 17));
        dates1.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0), 4));

        var dates2 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
        dates2.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0), 1));
        dates2.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0), 1 ));
        dates2.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 5,0,0), 17 ));

        var e = dates1.SelectMany((DateSpan x) =>
        {
            var result = new List<DateSpan>();
            foreach (var o in dates2.Where(y => x.StartDate < y.StartDate && y.StartDate < x.EndDate).ToList())
            {
                result.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(Math.Max(x.StartDate.Ticks, o.StartDate.Ticks)), new DateTime(Math.Min(x.EndDate.Ticks, o.EndDate.Ticks))));
            }
            return result;
        });
        //var d = dates1.Where(x => dates2.Any(y => x.StartDate < y.StartDate && y.StartDate < x.EndDate)).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code which is built based on your logic. Instead of using `where` and `any` combination, I just use cartesian product, which represents your logic lot more clearly. And just combined the `Min` and `Max` function to get you what you asked for

```
struct DateRange {
    public DateTime StartDate, EndDate;
    public override string ToString() {
        return $"{StartDate} - {EndDate}";
    }
};

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var list1 = new List<DateRange>() {
        new DateRange() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 5AM"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 10PM") },
        new DateRange() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2016 4AM"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2016 8AM") }
    };
    var list2 = new List<DateRange>() {
        new DateRange() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 10AM"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 11AM")},
        new DateRange() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 4PM"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2016 5PM")},
        new DateRange() { StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2016 5AM"), EndDate = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2016 10PM")}
    };

    var overlapList = from outer in list1
                        from inner in list2
                        where outer.StartDate < inner.EndDate && inner.StartDate < outer.EndDate
                        select new DateRange() {
                            StartDate = new DateTime(Math.Max(outer.StartDate.Ticks, inner.StartDate.Ticks)),
                            EndDate = new DateTime(Math.Min(outer.EndDate.Ticks, inner.EndDate.Ticks))
                        };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `let` clauses in order to make the code more readable:

```
var q = 
    from x in list1
    from y in list2
    let start = Max(x.StartDate, y.StartDate)
    let end = Min(x.EndDate, y.EndDate)
    where start < end
    select new { start, end };
foreach (var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.start}-{item.end}");
}
```

`Max` and `Min` methods are from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22692504/6659843).