# To compare the day , date , timestamp of two lines in file and output the latest day,date,timestamp

Tags: powershell

I have below lines from two different file having day , date ,timestamp. I need to output the line with latest timestamp.

The lines of one file :

`Tue 31/12/2000 17:13:29.83 - file copied`

And another file content is :

`Sun 17/07/1996 12:11:14.84 - drivers updated`

The output must be

`Tue 31/12/2000 17:13:29.83 - file copied`

How can we compare timestamp?

Comment: `31/12/2000` is a Sunday, not Tuesday. `17/07/1996` is a Wednesday, not Sunday. Are these mistakes by accident or is that the real content in the files?

Comment: @Theo, How can we suppress “ exception calling “”Parseexact”” with 3 arguments : string was not recognised as a valid Datetime”?

Comment: That depends on what the date you are parsing looks like. Both your examples have the wrong day name in front, hence my comment and that is why I strip it off in my answer. In cases like that, you need to check whatever is in the file and if indeed it **looks like** a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse out the date from these strings you can do:

```
# get the date and time from the string, remove the dayname as it is incorrect for that date
$dateString = ("Sun 31/12/2000 17:13:29.83 - file copied" -split '-')[0].Substring(4).Trim()
$date1 = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff', [CultureInfo]"en-US")

# do the same for the date in the second file and call that $date2
```

Then simply compare the dates using

```
$theDateYouWant = if ($date1 -gt $date2) { $date1 } else { $date2 }
```

<sup>By stripping off the dayname, you can use `$null` or `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` instead of  `[CultureInfo]"en-US"`</sup>

Comment: fwiw - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985404/52598) is nice to replace the if statement: `new DateTime(Math.Min(Date1.Ticks, Date2.Ticks))`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, nice. In PowerShell syntax this would be `$theDateYouWant = [datetime]([math]::Max($date1.Ticks, $date2.Ticks))`